# How would you fix this cabinet not opening all the way?

Tags: repair, kitchens, installation, cabinets

I’d like to see what I can do to fix this very annoying problem I have with one of the cabinets in my kitchen.

Whoever installed it didn’t take into account the pillar behind the hinge, so it’s only able to swing open to about 50 to 60 degrees out rather than opening to the full 90 degrees or more that you would expect when opening a kitchen cabinet.

What would you do that’s the easiest fix for a novice DIYer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you do not have the two hinges adjusted the same way ... that is why the door hangs crooked ... just loosen both of the large front facing screws and then the door can slide further to left

Comment: There are special hinges designed to handle this situation.  But part of the problem is that you have two different hinges that don't swivel the same.

Answer (score 11):

You can change it so it opens the opposite direction.
**I.E.** Flip the door over and attach the hinges to the left side of the cabinet.

You can remove door by removing the screw on each hinge that holds them to the cabinet frame.     Once you have the door un-atached you can measure where the holes are, from top and bottom, on the right side and transfer those measurements to the left side. Then hold the door up so the hinge's line up with those the marks (*the marks should be visible in the slot of the hinges*) and use a pencil to trace the shape of the hole, an oval, in the hinge.

Next you want to drill a small pilot hole directly in the middle of those two ovals, The drill bit should be smaller than the screws and you only need to drill them about 3/4 of an inch deep. ( *in your photo it appears that there may already be a hole on the left side for the hinges, some cabinets are made to have the door mount on either side.*)

You can now hold the door up in place and secure it to the cabinet with one screw in each hinge. The hole in the hinge is oval to allow you to adjust the door up or down a little so it lines up with the door next to it.

Now your door handle will be in the wrong place at the bottom of the door. Remove the handle and find a drill bit that fits in the existing screw hole. Measure from side and edge to the hole and transfer that to the top of the door so you can drill a new hole for the handle.

You can fill the old hole with some wood filler or vinyl wall Spackle and touch up with white paint.

Now you door will open in the opposite direction and it will no longer be restricted by the column.

Answer (score 5):

There are hinges in that style which will not hit the pillar. The tradeoff will be that the hinges themselves have significantly bulkier mechanisms. Depending on the brand of hinge they have names like "zero protrusion" or "continuous hinges". Anything that opens more than 90 degrees (such as hinges meant for corner cabinets) will also probably probably open without hitting your wall (but you'll want to add your own stop to prevent banging the door).

Example (not chosen to fit the existing drill pattern of your door, just to illustrate the hinge mechanism):

[image: Duomatic 165 Degree Full Overlay Self Close Logica Mounting Mod 17 Hinge]

Comment: It won't work as there isn't enough space between the edge of the cupboard and the wall.

Comment: @Tim The hinge on the corner cabinet in my own kitchen only needs a couple of millimeters on the hinge side as it starts opening. When fully open it's actually farther away from the hinge side than when it is closed. OP didn't include measurements, but based on how far the door is open in their picture it would work.